# AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table and other IOMMU-linked errors

Tags: drivers, 19.04, amd-ryzen

im running Ubuntu 19.04 on my Huawei Matebook D14 with Ryzen 2500U and 8GB of RAM onboard. Few days ago I started getting a system error pop-up after logging in (it doesn't cause any boot problem or etc, I'm able to normally use OS; I'm just tired of closing this pop-up every time I turn on my computer). Here're my dmesg errors:

```
grzechu@kasztany-i3:~$ dmesg --level=err
[    0.086693] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
[    0.086695] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
[    0.086696] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : No southbridge IOAPIC found
[    0.086696] AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
[    1.221347] AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
[    1.332681] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x8f7a6000-0x8f7a9fff]
[    1.514186] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    1.514188] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[    1.514838] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    3.128456] snd_pci_acp3x 0000:02:00.5: Invalid ACP audio mode : 1
[    3.844528] kfd kfd: Failed to resume IOMMU for device 1002:15dd
[    3.844849] kfd kfd: device 1002:15dd NOT added due to errors
```

I belive that this popup is caused by those "Firmware Bugs". I've tried Googling them and they are probably linked to something called IOMMU (?). After short research I've tried updating bios (I've got latest version avaiable) and turning something called virtualization technology (?) in my bios. None of those solutions worked for me.

Is there any way of getting rid of them?

Is it possible that this system error pop-up is NOT caused by those "Firmware Bugs"?